# Ion select show selected value

Tags: angular, ionic3, ion-select

I build a mobile app with Ionic and I have an ion-select which always displays three dots as list no matter what the selected value is.
What I want to do is to show the selected value of the ion-select.
Can anybody tell me how?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You must give more space to the ion-select.

Comment: I will check. You think the dots come from not enough space??

Comment: yes, if u have a problem with the binding, it throw an exception parsing html. can you show your ion-select?